# Meteor.js Publishing and Subscribing?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Okay, so I am a bit confused about something with Meteor.js. I created a site with it to test the various concepts, and it worked fine. Once I removed "insecure" and "autopublish", I get multiple "access denied" errors when trying to retrieve and push to the server. I belive it has something to do with the following snippet:

```
Template.posts.posts = function () {
    return Posts.find({}, {sort: {time: -1}});
}
```

I think that it is trying to access the collection directly, which it was allowed to do with "insecure" and "autopublish" enabled, but once they were disabled it was given access denied. Another piece I think is problematic:

```
else {
    Posts.insert({
    user: Meteor.user().profile.name,
    post: post.value,
    time: Date.now(),
});
```

I think that the same sort of thing is happening: it is trying to access the collection directly, which it is not allowed to do.

My question is, how do I re-factor it so that I do not need "insecure" and "autopublish" enabled?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Final:

```
/** 
* Models
*/
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');

posts = Posts

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.subscribe('posts');


}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
        return posts.find({}, {time:-1, limit: 100});
   });


    posts.allow({

        insert: function (document) {
            return true;
        },
        update: function () {
            return false;
        },
        remove: function () {
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: yes, you declare the variable 'Posts' but try to access it with 'posts' on the server.  You should correct the typo as now you have a question and answer showing code which won't run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so there are two parts to this question:

**Autopublish**

To publish databases in meteor, you need to have code on both the server-side, and client-side of the project. Assuming you have instantiated the collection (`Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts')`), then you need

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('posts', function(subsargs) {
        //subsargs are args passed in the next section
        return posts.find()
        //or 
        return posts.find({}, {time:-1, limit: 5}) //etc
   })
}
```

Then for the client

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('posts', subsargs) //here is where you can pass arguments
}
```

**Insecure**

The purpose of insecure is to allow the client to indiscriminately add, modify, and remove any database entries it wants. However, most of the time you don't want that. Once you remove insecure, you need to set up rules on the server detailing who can do what. These two functions are db.allow and db.deny. E.g.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    posts.allow({ 
        insert:function(userId, document) {
            if (userId === "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP") {  //e.g check if admin
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        update: function(userId,doc,fieldNames,modifier) {
            if (fieldNames.length === 1 && fieldNames[0] === "post") { //they are only updating the post
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        remove: function(userId, doc) {
            if (doc.user === userId) {  //if the creator is trying to remove it
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Likewise, db.deny will behave the exact same way, except a response of `true` will mean "do not allow this action"

Hope this answers all your questions

Comment: When you say `insert:function(userId, document)` or `update: function(userId,doc,fieldNames,modifier)`, how do you pass those arguments? And, do you do so from client or server?

Comment: You don't call those functions per se. They are called by meteor on certain events, and passed those arguments by the caller. Does this make sense?

Comment: Mmkay, so they're called by certain events...but I'm not sure I understand how the arguments are passed. Could you provide (or link to) an example where a piece of client code triggers the insert/update/remove functions and the arguments are passed?

Comment: If on the client side, you make a call to db.update, such as `posts.remove({key: value})`, then the function you pass to `posts.allow({remove: .... })` on the server side will be called with the userId of the client and the document they are trying to remove. If that function returns `true`, then they are allowed to delete it. Otherwise, the document remains. `update` and `insert` behave similarly

Comment: Cool! But where is the userId of the client obtained from, if not from the client-side posts.remove/update/insert call directly?

Comment: The client function that you call with posts.xxxx will automatically grab your userId, among other things, and then pass it to the server. The server will do some stuff with it, and then call the appropriate posts.allow using that as an argument.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Is whatever it grabs documented anywhere? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I don't know of any documentation for that, but meteor is open source, so you can try looking there (https://github.com/meteor/meteor). Hope this helps