# Meteor.js Publishing and Subscribing 2

Tags: javascript, meteor

I had another recent question on the same topic (for posterity: [Meteor.js Publishing and Subscribing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947266/meteor-js-publishing-and-subscribing)).

I have a test Meteor site. I have the following in a file on the root directory:

```
/** 
* Models
*/

Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');


posts = Posts;

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.subscribe('posts');

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
        return posts.find({}, {time:-1, limit: 100});
   });


    posts.allow({

        insert: function (document) {
            return true;
        },
        update: function () {
            return false;
        },
        remove: function () {
            return false;
        },

    });

}
```

What happened was that I made an edit, and it stopped working (on the dev. server: localhost:3000). I reverted the edit back, but I guess something changed, because it no longer works.

The client does have access to the Collection (the list of posts loads) so that isn't the issue.

The issue is that the second the client submits a post, it appears for a second on the list then disappears.

It seems similar behavior to when the client doesn't have publishing rights, but as you can see above I have given it.

When I go to the JS Console in Chrome, no "access denied" or error comes up.

When I try 'adding a post' from the Console, the same sort of behavior happens. A flicker, then it's gone.

What's going on? Is it just a weird Meteor glitch? Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

OK, clearly some sort of internal Meteor glitch; a "meteor reset" fixed the problem with NO CHANGE in the code itself.

So I guess problem solved!

*EDIT 2*

Noooo. Problem not solved. It appeared again.

It seems to reject them once the number of posts reaches a certain threshold, which leads me to believe it has something to do with the "limit".

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your client has 100 posts in its local cache. Then when the client inserts a new post, it's inserted directly into the client cache (so it does now contain 101 posts) and in the background it's sent to the server. The server inserts it into the real database, and then tells the client to remove one of it's cached posts, since it's supposed to only store 100 posts in it's cache. This is probably what's happening to you.

Comment: Very well possible, but if this was true wouldn't refreshing the page show the post that was posted previously, instead of only the posts that were posted before reaching the limit?

Comment: @Aristides What you're saying is true if you order the posts that way (and a refresh wouldn't be necessary). But if you run `Posts.insert({whatever})` in the javascript console in the browser, you get an error message (that the insert failed?)? Or when does the error message show up? Do the collection has any deny rules?

Comment: No, no insert failed error message (no error msg at all actually). The client is allowed to add only, no update or delete. But not even the add is working (if it's past 100 items).